# Generating url with parameters from JS variables in TWIG

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I'm have a pretty silly issue.
I'm trying to generate an url in twig using JS variables.

---

It works when I write them manually:

```
var url = "{{ path('geolocation', {'latitude':'41.39109','longitude':'2.15485','accuracy':'1114'}) }}";
```

but it doesn't when I use variables instead:

```
var url = "{{ path('geolocation', {'latitude':latitude,'longitude':longitude,'accuracy':accuracy}) }}";
```

What could be happening?
Of course the variables exist and are correctly defined.

---

It seems it doesn't get the parameter correctly:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Parameter "accuracy" for route "geolocation" must match "[^/]++" (""
>   given) to generate a corresponding URL.").

But when I go:

```
console.log(latitude + " " + longitude + " " + accuracy);
```

the result is

> 41.39109 2.15485 1114

Comment: which framework do you use?

Comment: Your variables are defined in the js script (client side), not in the twig (backend side). You have to use `$this->render('nameofmy.html.twig', array('latitude' => X, 'longitude' => Y, 'accuracy' => Z);` in the controller action.

Comment: Shame on me. That's it.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html):

```
var url = Routing.generate('geolocation', { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, accuracy:accuracy })
```

NB: Take care of add the correct js file inclusion and to expose the route of the controller as described in the doc.

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with TWIG but in regular JS your URL is being assigned a string and Javascript cannot/does not replace variable names within normal strings. You will need to do something like:

```
  var url = "{{ path('geolocation', {'latitude':" + latitude + ",'longitude':" + longitude + ",'accuracy':" + accuracy + "}) }}";
```

ES6, if you can use it has another way, back tick strings  :

```
  var url = `{{ path('geolocation', {'latitude':${latitude},'longitude':${longitude},'accuracy':${accuracy}"}) }}`;
```

Which mark the expressions to be evaluated by enclosing them in ${...}

Comment: `path` is a twig function that already will rendered before sending output to the the client. That's why this aproach won't work as the javascript variables are defined client-side and are unknown while rendering the template